# Test Kitchen says php-mysql is not installed

Tags: chef-infra, php-5.5, test-kitchen

I'm new to Chef. I [think I] am installing `php-mysql` using

```
package 'php-mysql' do
    action :install
    notifies :restart, 'httpd_service[apps]'
end
```

However, when I run the test

```
describe package 'php-mysql' do
    it { should be_installed }
end
```

It fails saying `System Package php-mysql should be installed (expected that 'System Package php-mysql' is installed)`.

Moreover, other packages as `php-pdo`, `php-intl`, their tests passes. (declaration and tests are exactly the same, just change the name).

I'm using remi repo for php 5.5 packages with the [yum-remi-chef cookbok](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/yum-remi-chef).

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

By running `package 'php-pdo_mysql'` I get the following output;

```
yum_package[php-pdo_mysql] action install[2016-10-14T20:24:00+00:00] WARN: yum_package[php-pdo_mysql] matched multiple Provides for php-pdo_mysql but we can only use the first match: php-mysql. Please use a more specific version.

           - install version 5.4.45-12.el6.remi of package php-mysql
```

Is it installing the wrong version?, since it says `5.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because **php-mysql** package doesn't exist anymore for 5.5+.

The *mysql*, *mysqli* and *pdo_mysql* extensions are now provided by the **php-mysqlnd** package.

The old php-mysql package was using libmysqlclient instead of mysqlnd.

See [Overview of the MySQL PHP drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php)

P.S. installation works, because yum pulls the right package.

Comment: Please don't forget that PHP 5.5 is now EOL, not maintained, even if my repository provides some security backports, time to plan an update to 5.6 or greater.

Comment: Yes I know it's not maintained. Our system runs on 5.5 so that's why we're using it. We do plan, however, to migrate to php 7.0

Comment: So I have to install `php-mysqlnd` instead of `php-mysql` and `php-pdo`?

Comment: As I said "yum install php-mysql" works (if you need the "mysql" extension which is deprecated). Only the test need to be fixed. I you need "pdo_mysql" extension: "yum install php-pdo_mysql" ;) Don't rely on package name, but on the extension name you really need (the package layout have changed, and may change again).

Comment: Oh I understand. Yes, what I need is `pdo_mysql` extension.

Comment: I ran it with the package name `php-pdo_mysql` but it seems it's installing the incorrect one. I updated my answer with the output from stdout

Comment: If it pulls 5.4.45, this means remi-php55 repo is not enabled.